# Samsung Galaxy S Captivate power button

Tags: buttons, samsung-captivate

My captivate's power button was acting up a few weeks ago. But the other day it just completely stopped working! I either have to plug it in to my charger or completely take my phone apart and take the battery out and put it back in. It's weird because it's like the power button is stuck or something. The power off screen comes up and I don't know it's just frustrating. What can I do to repair it? Is it worth repairing? Should I wait for my upgrade in June and go on with this problem? or Should I just throw the phone away and go without it until june? Please help! Thanks!

Comment: I would try factory resetting the phone, just to rule out any software issues (like a recently installed app acting up.)  If it's truly a hardware problem, there isn't much you can do other than taking the phone to where you bought it and seeing if it's still under warranty.